# PHP necessity to check for DB connection errors

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, error-handling

Since I am trying to provide well formatted code as much as possible, I came up to this question.

In general I check for a database connection error for every prepared statement I create like:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("...random SQL code here...") {
    //bind_param, executes, store_results, etc. here
} else {$err = "Database error";}
```

But I never check for a database errors on executes. Should I do it?

Does it hurt the performance on big projects more as it would solve a better debugging with more chance on throwing out an useful error code? Or should I forget about those checks at all and just rely on mysql/php/apache logs?

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should test validity of your connection and no it will not affect the performance of your script. The php documentation on those connection commands nearly allways show yoou how.

See there

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        .$mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Well I had more something in mind like :

I made some querys and out of blue my database throw out some errors or do not work anymore. Then it wont help if I did some thousands line ago one $mysqli->connect_error { ... } or ?

Comment: If something breaks after connect and during a query, your execute call would not return a valid result. You already check that. In addition to that, a full run of a php app usually takes milliseconds. So, the connect will probably always be your first notice of a problem with a died db.